# Golang websocket client, close connection after getting result

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

How I can implement this kind of scenario:

1.I have LoginHandler which receives some user data - email and signedXml:

```
func LoginHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    var (
        err  error
        data LoginPost
    )
    if err = c.BindJSON(&data); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"status": "error"})
        return
    }

    ...

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "ok"})
}
```

2.I need to send signedXml to another server via websocket

3.Save result (success or error)

4.Close connection

Every HTTP request will open connection, send 1 message, get 1 result and finally close socket. I was trying with channel, but no success. Is this possible to implement my case?

**UPDATE**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/url"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "net/http"
)

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    message := r.FormValue("message")
    w.Write([]byte(message))
}

func postHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var (
        message = r.FormValue("message")
        u = url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: "echo.websocket.org", Path: "/"}
        err error
        out []byte
        conn *websocket.Conn
    )
    log.Printf("message: %s\n", message)
    log.Printf("connecting to %s\n", u.String())
    conn, _, err = websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dial:", err)
    }
    log.Println("write")
    if err = conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(message)); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("write:", err)
    }
    log.Println("read")
    if _, out, err = conn.ReadMessage(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("read:", err)
    }
    w.Write(out)
    log.Println("close")
    conn.Close()
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/post", postHandler).Methods("POST")
    http.Handle("/", r)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: Are you able to change the other server? Websockets don't really seem appropriate for this situation.

Comment: [Dial](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Dialer.Dial) a connection, [write a message](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.WriteMessage), [read](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.ReadMessage) a message and then [close](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.Close) the connection.  There's no need to use channels.  Show what you tried so far.

Comment: I tried example from https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/client.go. But they listen until interrupt signal received and then close connection. How I can rewrite that example without channels and for-select statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [Dial](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Dialer.Dial), [WriteMessage](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.WriteMessage), [ReadMessage](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.ReadMessage) and [Close](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.Close) in sequence.

```
c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(url, nil)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, signedXML)
if err != nil {
     // handle error
}
_, p, err := c.ReadMessage()
if err != nil {
     // handle error
}
c.Close()

// p is a []byte with the first received message.
```

Comment: I tested code above (UPDATE*) and it freezes after `conn.ReadMessage()`

Comment: The code in the update works for me.  `curl -d message=hello http://localhost:8080/post` prints `hello`.